Role of particle number conservation for SPT order
It is shown in https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6341, that non interacting SPT phases of fermions are at least protected by U(1) symmetry (a.k.a. particle number conservation). I wondered if this result also generalizes to interacting SPT phases, i.e. can U(1) symmetry by itself stabilize an interacting SPT phase. As per my knowledge with 1D interacting SPT phases, U(1) symmetry does not fractionalize and thus cannot lead to non-trivial edge modes (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3323). This result then imply that the non interacting result does not generalize to interacting systems. Is this indeed the case? If so, why U(1) plays a role for non interacting systems but not for interacting systems? (if there is a reasoning apart from the fact that U(1) cannot fractionalize and thus not lead to non trivial edge modes)
PS: In https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3323, it is mentioned that if translation and U(1) both are considered then indeed different average particle number can lead to different phases. My question is slightly different since I am only interested in different phases arising from same onsite average particle number. This is indeed possible for non interacting systems if I am not mistaken with my interpretation of https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6341
